# How to correctly pass a function to another function in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to assign a separate function to each instance that is created from `bgImages`, so that when I call `instance.collisiontext`, it calls that function.  I feel like I am doing something wrong.  If you look down in the build, you can see an example of where I create an instance and assign a function to `collidetext`.

The whole point of the `collisiontext` method is to call the function assigned to `collidetext` (which is going to be a different function for each instance).

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, when assigning a function to the instance slum, do I need to keep the '()' after 'slumnotice'?

```
class BgImages(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Npcs, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.collidetext=''

    def collisiontext(self,**kwargs):
        global collidetext
        return collidetext()

class MainCharacter(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainCharacter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)

    elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            for i in listofwidgets:
                if i.collide_point(self.x,self.top):
                    self.y -=1
                    i.collisiontext()

class gameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        slum=BgImages(source='slum.png', collidetext=slumnotice())
        listofwidgets=[]
        listofwidgets.append(slum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Quite a bit. It'll be easier if I just correct it and you figure out what I did after:

```
class BgImages(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.collidetext = kwargs['collidetext']
        del kwargs['collidetext']
        super(BgImages, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def collisiontext(self):
        return self.collidetext()
```

> Also, when assigning a function to the instance slum, do I need to keep the '()' after 'slumnotice'?

That would depend on whether you want to use `slumnotice` itself or the return value of `slumnotice()`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you did with kwargs['collidetext']

Comment: It's a dictionary. I accessed and mutated it.

Comment: Why?  Anyway, that gives me error,  'KeyError: 'collidetext''

Comment: Can I just have the 'collidetext' be a placeholder for whatever function i assign to it (without having to delete things)?

Comment: Are you actually passing a "collidetext" argument to the constructor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, or what a constructor is (sorry, I'm not very good at this stuff).  But, slumnotice which is a completely separate function (not included in the example code above), is being assigned to collidetext, when the slum instance is created.

Comment: `BgImages()` would be the constructor. It *requires* a `collidetext` argument or it will give you that exception. `BgImages(collidetext=somefunction)`

Comment: So can I give it a blank argument?  When slum instance is created, it should assign slumnotice function to collidetext.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "blank argument" in Python. Either you pass an argument, or you do not.

Comment: If I remove self.collidetext in the constructor, I get error BGImages has no attribute 'collidetext'.  So what do I do with self.collidetext inside the constructor?

Comment: So I can just give it a random argument and it wouldn't really matter, since every instance of BgImages will have assigned it's own function to collidetext. ?

Comment: You assign to it, just as the initializer (`__init__`) already does. You can give it any arbitrary argument, but as coded the `BgImages.collisiontext()` method will attempt to call it.